# Running function after async function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

Im trying to write a code that runs async function and when its done, it runs another piece of code.

I've tried putting the async function in a  promise (as seen in the code below) and using the `then` method without success.

***what happens inside the function doesn't really matter but I've included it anyways in case Im mistaking and it does..***

```
getData = async(file) =>{
        let data = await fetch(file);
        data = await data.text();
        return(data);
    }

    getDataAndUsername = async() => {
        this.setState({data: JSON.parse(await this.getData("/getData"))});
        this.setState({username: await this.getData("/user")});
        console.log('done');
    }
```

getDataAndUsername is the async function Im trying to run before the other functions.

```
CheckInDataBase = (username) => {
        console.log('checking In DataBase');
        this.state.data.forEach((element)=>{
            if(element.username === username){
                    this.setState({exist: true});
                }
            });
            if (!(this.state.exist)){
            axios.post('/createUser', {"username": username, "status": "Working"});
            this.setState({exist: true});
        }
        }
```

this is the regular function Im trying to run after the async one

and this is the code:

```
new Promise((res) => {
            this.getDataAndUsername();
            res();
        }).then(
            this.CheckInDataBase(this.state.username)
        )
```

whats happenning right now is that, the this.CheckInDatabase runs before the getDataAndUsername is finished.

Comment: Why don't you `await this.getDataAndUsername();`?

Comment: @sjahan becuase theyre not inside a async function, I cant

Comment: You're using this.setState too often in your functions. It's working asynchronously. Try to return the values instead of updating the state. `CheckInDataBase` might have a problem: the `this.setState({exist: true});` inside the loop might not be propagated before the `if (!(this.state.exist))` executes

Comment: @eitanr if your function is awaiting something, then, it is `async`, so why not giving it the `async` keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being defined as `async`, your `getDataAndUsername` is already a Promise, there is no need to wrap it in a `new Promise()`. You can just do:

```
this.getDataAndUsername().then( _ => {
  this.CheckInDataBase(this.state.username);
})
```

And it should work.

#### Why your code didn't work in the first place

You were creating a new promise with this:

```
new Promise((res) => {
            this.getDataAndUsername();
            res();
        }) ...
```

There, you're calling `this.getDataAndUsername()`, but are ignoring wether it resolves or not. That code will call  `res` instantly, thus `checkInDatabase` was being called before `getDataAndUsername` resolved.

You cold, instead, wait for `getDataAndUsername` to resolve:

```
new Promise((res) => {
            return this.getDataAndUsername().then(_ => {res()})
        }) ...
```

The point would be to wait for the promise to resolve using `then`, and also adding a `return`.

However, as stated above, there is no need to do this because `getDataAndUsername` is already a Promise.

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth answer! youve been really helpful!

Comment: There is still a problem: `this.getDataAndUsername()` updates the state asynchronously and there's a risk that `this.CheckInDataBase(this.state.username)` . The `this.state.username` and `this.state.data` might be old at the time of looping through `data` and the functionality will crash in this case

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comments, you're updating the state too often. It's an asynchronous process, so you might end up by checking or looping through an old state.

I suggest you to use `this.setState` as less as possible and return the values instead in as much functions as possible. This way you'll split the functionality and not rely on react's state.

Here is my proposal for your problem:

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  getData = async (file) =>{
    let data = await fetch(file);
    return await data.text();
  };

  getDataAndUsername = async () => ({
    data: JSON.parse(await this.getData("/getData")),
    username: JSON.parse(await this.getData("/user"))
  });

  checkInDataBase = ({ username, data }) => {
    console.log('checking In DataBase');
    return !!data.find(element => element.username === username);
  };

  addUser = async username => await axios.post('/createUser', {"username": username, "status": "Working"});

  myCheckFunction = async () => {
    const dataAndUsername = await this.getDataAndUsername();
    if (dataAndUsername) {
      if (!this.checkInDataBase(dataAndUsername)) {
        const newUser = await this.addUser(dataAndUsername.username);
        dataAndUsername.data.push(newUser);
      }
      // A single place where you update the state
      this.setState({
        ...dataAndUsername,
        exists: true
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time helping me relaize and solve my mistakes! youve been really helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
this.getDataAndUsername().then((response) => {
  /**
   * Your code that you want to run after getDataAndUsername
   */
}, (error) => {
  /**
   * Handle error here
   */
});
```

Or with `async/await`:

```
(async function() {
  try {
    const dataAndUsername = await this.getDataAndUsername();
    /**
     * Your code that you want to run after getDataAndUsername
     */

  } catch(e) {
    /**
   * Handle error here
   */
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thats wired.. I rember trying this and it didnt work, but anyway it works now, thank you very much!